# Subscribing to calendar push notifications : Getting too many notifications

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm subscribing to [Calendar Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push) to get notified via web hook when some resources change on a specific user.

The subscription is created without any issue, but then I receive a notification about every 10 to 20 seconds (while I'm not interacting with the calendar at all!)

I do reply with a 200 to these notifications, these are separate messages (but for the same channel/subscription)

Any idea what might be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there @TristanFoureur! Could you please share some example push notifications so we all can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Google Workspace domain you can use the [Admin Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/calendar) to inspect/correlate the calendar events.
Also may find more useful to handle the push notifications in that same [API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/watch).